# 2 Email contact form Validation with security code in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email, contact-form

I'm having trouble making this properly work.

What I want to happen is for someone to be able to fill out the given information but there's an email validation which is just you put your email in Email: and is suppose to match in Verify Email: then in hopes that they did that write and if they answer the spam question right which is just "what is 5+5?" then the form will send to my email

The problem is that, although the email validation is working, the spam question even if you write the answer wrong, the form is still sent. I need it so that the spam and the email validation either or must be correct or the form won't send.

I hope made this simple for some to understand and help me out! Here's my PHP code. Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script>


<?php

$email1=$_POST['Email1'];
$email2=$_POST['Email2'];
$from=$_POST['Email1'];
$email="!YOUREMAIL@GOES.HERE!";
$subject="maintenance Request";
$message=$_POST['Box'];
$select=$_POST['Select'];
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$number=$_POST['Question'];
$message="Name:   ".$name. "\r\n" ."\r\n" . "Email:   " .$from ."\r\n" . "\r\n" . "Comment:   " .$message ."\r\n" . "\r\n" . "Selected Machine:   " .$select;


if($number==10) {

}


if(filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
}
if (filter_var($email2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mail ($email, $subject, $message, "from:".$from);
echo 'Thanks You for the Maintenance Request! We will Contact you shortly. ';
}
else {
    echo "This ($email2) email address is different from ($email1).\n";
}

?>
</script>
```

Comment: i left the "if ($number=10){ }" alone sense i did know what to do with it to make it work.

Comment: Where are you checking if the two emails are the same?

Comment: @Barmar                                                                   
                                                                                  
                                                                                  
      if(filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
}
if (filter_var($email2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mail ($email, $subject, $message, "from:".$from);
echo 'Thanks You for the Maintenance Request! We will Contact you shortly. ';
}
else {
    echo "This ($email2) email address is different from ($email1).\n";
}

?>

Comment: That doesn't check if they're the same. It just checks if they're both valid emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answer to the validation question is wrong, you should print a message and exit the script.

```
if ($number != 10) {
    die("You are not a human!");
}
```

You're also never checking if the two emails are the same.

```
if(!filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Invalid email ($email1)");
}
if ($email1 == $email2) {
    mail ($email, $subject, $message, "from:".$from);
    echo 'Thanks You for the Maintenance Request! We will Contact you shortly. ';
}
else {
    echo "This ($email2) email address is different from ($email1).\n";
}
```

There's no need to call `filter_var()` on `$email2`. If it's equal to `$email1` then it must be valid. If it's not equal to `$email1`, we don't care if it's valid.

Comment: I just checked my html POST name and I had it to something else, and the PHP works now and everything is working as planed, Thank you so much for the help @Barmar